Does it matter where you put things in the microwave?
One thing I  know about microwaves is they have standing waves such that if you put food all over them it will heat up at different rates.  This is to do with the creation of a standing wave, from the wavelength of which one can work out the speed of light.  This is elegantly demonstrated here, an image from which is below.  The distance between the hotspots depends on the frequency of the microwave, 2.45MHz is common which gives a distance of 6cm.
Suppose one is heating something smaller than 6 cm, say a cup of thick soup.  Where would be the best place to put it?  Without actually knowing, I can think of three contradictory arguments:

It does not matter.  If there is only one thing in the microwave all the energy will end up in it.
It is better to put it right in the middle.  They always build them with a hotspot there (as per image) so it will work most efficiently.
It is better to not put it in the middle, as this means it is moving about and the heat will be more evenly distributed within the cup.

Where is the best place to put something like a cup of thick soup in a microwave?


We had a problem with a (former) microwave and the repair tech told us two things. Put something at the edge of the rotating glass to encourage more even heating. And NEVER open the door without pressing stop or pause first as the switch that turns off the microwave when you open the door is a common failure point.

Dont put it in the middle.  If the microwaves arent hitting the middle much, obviously it will take longer to cook.  From a few videos online that I have actually seen on this, they always say put it on the edge of the spinning plate, as to make sure the food passes through the outer diameter and passes evenly through the microwaves.

I have researched this task for a science experiment. The results did show that the food is heated better when placed on the outside of the spinning plate. My results are here.
Middle
67.2,
68.3,
67.8,
/Outside
74.9,
73.2,
71
The experiment was done with water, and I set the time to 1 minute.
I used a round container about 15 centimeters in radius. I tipped 1/2 cup of water and a digital thermometer for the temperature testing

This is interesting, the difference in temperature is significant.  If you can provide further details I would probably accept this answer.  How big were the containers of water?  Where were they put?

TLDR - just set it a little bit off center or actually test your hot spots by various means by searching for "find hot spots in you microwave" at your favorite search engine.
Your food will heat fine no matter where you put it. All of this is for a little bit more efficiency and because it is interesting. There are lots of microwaves bouncing around inside the appliance that interfere with themselves causing peaks and valleys of energy. The center was designed to be a low point because you have a spinning tray and just outside (like centimeters) that low point is ever increasing heat.
So unless your cup is the size of a marshmallow, it will not make a whole lot of difference because of conductive heat transfer after the radiation heat transfer from the microwaves nearer to the edge of your cup. And then there is actuality where the microwaves are just all different due to allowed manufacturing tolerances and usage.

I wasn't being sarcastic. Only really small foods would benefit from placing outside of the center. Its still gonna land under one of the many "hot spots". Smear butter evenly on large plate. Microwave it for 15/20 seconds. You'll see the spots aren't that far apart.

This is a confusing answer. I can't tell what you're advocating or how you meant to resolve the contradiction you raised (what's evenly distributed? How does that help?). Can you organize your thoughts and clarify your stance?

I apologize. You are right. I am not sure how to explain it without a drawing.

Much improved! +1.
